# Created a card that toggles with useState on a list, but it toggles all the items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-state

Here's the component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function AdminsComponent() {
  const [secondCard, setSecondCard] = useState(false)

  const toggleSetSecondCard = () => {
    setSecondCard(!secondCard)
  }

  const adminsComponent = adminData.map((user) => (
    <li
      key={user.index}
      className="px-4 my-1 lg:pl-8 w-full scale-95 transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-100 text-left"
      onClick={toggleSetSecondCard}
    >
     // codehere
    </li>
      
      {secondCard && (
        <div className="px-4 border-l-4 p-2 bg-accent-0 text-accent-8 pb-4 shadow-lg border-blue">
          // ... codehere
        </div>
      )}

  ))

  return <ul>{adminsComponent}</ul>
}
```

I removed all the things it have inside to simplify, but basically i created a useState function in which, when i click any of the `<li>` rendered, it shows the div inside the

`{secondCard && ()}`

But it is toggling the div for all of the `<li>` at the same time. I want it individually just for the `<li>` i clicked. How could i achieve that?

Comment: Well, you should create a new component containing the `<li />` tags and move the secondCard state there. So it is only triggered for the one component you click on, instead for all.

Comment: But how would that differ? I mean, i would only move the code to a new component separatedly, but the logic would be the same, right?

Comment: Basically yes. But so every card has it's own state instead of one shared state of all cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `li` need to have it's own state. Either by using useState() with an array of boolean mapped to the users, or by having their own component, with their own state, like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Card = (props) => {
  const [secondCard, setSecondCard] = useState(false);

  const toggleSetSecondCard = () => {
    setSecondCard(!secondCard);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <li
        key={props.user.index}
        className="px-4 my-1 lg:pl-8 w-full scale-95 transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-100 text-left"
        onClick={toggleSetSecondCard}
      >
        {props.user.name}
      </li>
      {secondCard && (
        <div className="px-4 border-l-4 p-2 bg-accent-0 text-accent-8 pb-4 shadow-lg border-blue">
          Hi
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default function AdminsComponent() {
  let adminData = [
    { name: "asger", index: 1 },
    { name: "viggo", index: 2 }
  ];

  return (
    <ul>
      {adminData.map((user) => (
        <Card user={user} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

The tradeoff with this solution is that one component can't change state in other components, so if you want a "close all" or ensure that only one card is ever shown at a time, you would need the other approach.

Here's an example of how to allow only one open secondCard at a time:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function AdminsComponent() {
  let adminData = [
    { name: "asger", index: 1 },
    { name: "viggo", index: 2 }
  ];

  const [openCard, setOpenCard] = useState(0);

  return (
    <ul>
      {adminData.map((user) => {
        return (
          <>
            <li
              key={user.index}
              className="px-4 my-1 lg:pl-8 w-full scale-95 transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-100 text-left"
              onClick={() => setOpenCard(openCard == user.index ? 0 : user.index)}
            >
              {user.name}
            </li>
            {openCard == user.index && (
              <div className="px-4 border-l-4 p-2 bg-accent-0 text-accent-8 pb-4 shadow-lg border-blue">
                Hi
              </div>
            )}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Tried that. It is still toggling all at the same time, and also when i have the card open, if i click it again it does not close, and it was doing that before thanks to my `toggleSetSecondCard` function.

Comment: @HenriqueMonteiro which one did you try? I have just run these and they do only one card at a time... true that the last example does not close when you click again. Just need to set the state back to zero for that to happen.

Comment: @HenriqueMonteiro you can try the first sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-meadow-gqf1l?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @HenriqueMonteiro I have updated the second sample now too...

Comment: In fact i did tried yours, and if i use exactly your code, it runs correctly. But i dont have a hardcoded array, my data comes from an API, and when i use that data, it open all at the same time.

Comment: Ah ok. May I first ask if you used the first or the last example in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are using one state element to toggle the entire list.

Problem with the approach is, once the state got toggled, it will be changed for all the elements. Better approach initalize the state as an array and based on index keep shuffling the states.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function AdminsComponent() {
 const [secondCard, setSecondCard] = useState(Array(adminData.length).fill(false))

 const toggleSetSecondCard = (i) => {
   setSecondCard([...secondCard][i]=!secondCard[i]);
 }

 const adminsComponent = adminData.map((user,i) => (
   <li
     key={user.index}
     className="px-4 my-1 lg:pl-8 w-full scale-95 transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-100 text-left"
     onClick={e=>toggleSetSecondCard(i)}
   >
    // codehere
   </li>
     
     {secondCard && (
       <div className="px-4 border-l-4 p-2 bg-accent-0 text-accent-8 pb-4 shadow-lg border-blue">
         // ... codehere
       </div>
     )}

 ))

 return <ul>{adminsComponent}</ul>
}
```

Comment: I receved this as an error: `TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.`

On the `toggleSetSecondCard` function.